# Проблема с вёрсткой, позиционирование

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

В общем проблема в том, что не могу поставить footer в самый низ страницы, он постоянно куда-то скачет. Вот пример где он сейчас  https://o525.ru/QeujeQyQNHrkQOyE6ZHZT5RkuVk ( сам футр на сайте )
https://o525.ru/2M9-hDAuf34_nxcF2xPkMbtdcZE ( html )

Такие стили я ему задал:

```
.footer {
background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141,0.5);
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
font-size: medium
```

}
Пробовал с `relative` в `position`, он становится таким:
https://o525.ru/5rRKv-KVIr4osJ9sKbBAMHsXdQA

Попробовал использовать `display: inline;`, ничего близко к правильному результату, не получилось.

Comment: Сейчас появилось столько хороших вещей для позиционирования, а вы это используетe...)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footer {
  background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>
<footer class="footer">

</footer>
```

Код, конечно, не супер... но попробуйте так, у меня получилось:

```
.footer {
   background-color: rgb(141, 141, 141, 0.5);
   height: 50px;
 }

 body {
   margin: 0px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   background-image: url(../img/bg_main.png);
 }
```

Comment: Попробовал, не получилось( немного красивее стало ) 
https://o525.ru/4WR4igHfGD1MGaGR4g16ZOks39A

Comment: @Loney_Space, выложите весь свой код, а не отрывок

Comment: https://codepen.io/java7cript/pen/VJRWKa 
 Только тут всё сломалось.

Comment: @Loney_Space, поправил

Comment: А где посмотреть поправленный вариант?))
Можно, пожалуйста, ссылку?)

Comment: @Loney_Space, https://jsfiddle.net/12rtc7nb/1/

Answer (score 1):

После последнего блока с классом  "right_content" добавьте блок с классом "clearfix" (или любым другим названием класса, это не принципиально).
А в стилях пропишите`.clearfix {clear:both}`

Вот здесь исправленный вариант https://codepen.io/AnastasiiaIlina/pen/NZJvBK